# What is the purpose of creating a volume between two docker.sock files in Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mount, docker-volume

I see this in many docker apps that are somehow related hardly on networking, but I can't understand this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

> Let’s take a step back here. Do you really want Docker-in-Docker? Or
> do you just want to be able to run Docker (specifically: build, run,
> sometimes push containers and images) from your CI system, while this
> CI system itself is in a container?
>
> I’m going to bet that most people want the latter. All you want is a
> solution so that your CI system like Jenkins can start containers.
>
> And the simplest way is to just expose the Docker socket to your CI
> container, by bind-mounting it with the -v flag.
>
> Simply put, when you start your CI container (Jenkins or other),
> instead of hacking something together with Docker-in-Docker, start it
> with:
>
> docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
>
> Now this
> container will have access to the Docker socket, and will therefore be
> able to start containers. Except that instead of starting “child”
> containers, it will start “sibling” containers.